# Delegate System.Action does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c#, lambda, action

The action :

```
readonly Action _execute;

public RelayCommand(Action execute)
             : this(execute, null)
{
}

public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<Boolean> canExecute)
{
    if (execute == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
}
```

Other class's code:

```
public void CreateCommand()
{
    RelayCommand command = new RelayCommand((param)=> RemoveReferenceExcecute(param));}
}

private void RemoveReferenceExcecute(object param)
{
    ReferenceViewModel referenceViewModel = (ReferenceViewModel) param;
    ReferenceCollection.Remove(referenceViewModel);
}
```

Why do I get the following exception, how can I fix it?

> *Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments*

Comment: the code you have prsented **does not show** the line at which the error occurs. If you are using any IDE, please double-click on the error line, and the IDE will jump right to the offending line. If you are not using IDE, read the FULL log of errors, and the "file:number" will be presented somewhere. Without looking at the exact place, it's much harder to tell what's wrong. Having said that, and judging by the error message, I'm guessing that @JOHN has hit the point. Please attach relevant code next time! [here, it'd be the place where you try to execute the 'execute' delegate]

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Are you sure the error does not come from `RelayCommand command = new RelayCommand((param)=> RemoveReferenceExcecute(param));}`, which is in the question? Agreed with the sentiment, this should have been pointed out.

Comment: In the first class, `RelayCommand`, you have `_execute` as an `Action`. That's a delegate type that has 0 parameters and returns `void`. We can't see how `_execute` is used. But it is probably something like `_execute();` (note: 0 arguments). In the "other class", your method `CreateCommand` seems to create a `RelayCommand` but (unless there's more inside the `CreateCommand` body) it looks like it is not used or kept. The problem, as already pointed out, is that there is 1 argument on the left-hand side of your lambda arrow `=>`, but the delegate you use needs 0 arguments.

Comment: If you changed (for example) `Action` to `Action<object>`, then the signature of your `RemoveReferenceExcecute` would match, and this simple syntax would be allowed: `command = new RelayCommand(RemoveReferenceExcecute);` (by "method group" conversion).

Comment: @hvd: you are right, I've not noticed this one. If RelayCommand has only this one constructor, then surely this is the issue - `(param)` would not match the parameterless `Action`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`System.Action` is a delegate for parameterless function. Use `System.Action<T>`.

To fix this, replace your `RelayAction` class with something like the following

```
class RelayAction<T> {
    readonly Action<T> _execute;
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<Boolean> canExecute){
        //your code here
    }
    // the rest of the class definition
}
```

Note `RelayAction` class should become generic. Another way is to directly specify the type of parameter `_execute` will receive, but this way you'll be restricted in usage of your `RelayAction` class. So, there are some tradeoff between flexibility and robustness.

Some MSDN links:

1. [`System.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.action.aspx)
2. [`System.Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

Comment: If it's a class to implement [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx), the class should probably not be generic, and the delegate type should be `Action<object>`, because `object` is what its [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx) method is passed.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your command 'RemoveReferenceExcecute' without any parameters

```
RelayCommand command = new RelayCommand(RemoveReferenceExcecute);}
```

or you can pass some parameters / objects into it:

```
RelayCommand<object> command = new RelayCommand<object>((param)=> RemoveReferenceExcecute(param));}
```

In the second case do not forget to pass CommandParameter from your view;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is what happened.

This is the method that required an empty action

```
    public LTDescr setOnStart( Action onStart ){
        this._optional.onStart = onStart;
        return this;
    }
```

here is the way to call it

```
    .setOnStart(()=>{ 
            
    })
```