# Precompile Exception: Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c#, async-await, action, func

I'm trying to repair some code that I cloned from a public repo. It's an `async` method that's missing an `await` operator:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JsonPatchOperation>> GetRemoveAllRelationsOperations(IBatchMigrationContext batchContext, WorkItem targetWorkItem)
{
  return targetWorkItem.Relations?.Select((r, index) => MigrationHelpers.GetRelationRemoveOperation(index));
}
```

I'm trying this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JsonPatchOperation>> GetRemoveAllRelationsOperations(IBatchMigrationContext batchContext, WorkItem targetWorkItem)
{
  return await Task.Run(o => targetWorkItem.Relations?.Select((r, index) => MigrationHelpers.GetRelationRemoveOperation(index)));
}
```

...but I'm getting an error in the IDE:

> Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments

I found some similar discussions, but unfortunately none of them quite address the lambda syntax:

- [Delegate System.Action does not take 1 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14029596)
- [Delegate System.Action<dynamic,int> does not take `1' arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27068298)
- [Delegate `System.Func<bool>' does not take `1' arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38265565)
- [Delegate Action does not take 3 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23605507)

It appears the precompiler is interpreting the input as an `Action` when it should be seeing it as a `Func` instead. But I thought that the statement `o => ...` could indicate either.

I'm not familiar enough with C# to be able to work this one out. Can someone assist?

How do I tell the precompiler that I want to send a `Func` instead of an `Action`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the reason for the compilation error, is that `Task.Run` accepts a (non-generic) `Action`, which is a delegate that accepts no arguments.

You have tried to call `Task.Run` with a lambda accepting an argument `o`, so changing to this will remove the error:

```
Task.Run(() =>
```

The parentheses `()` denote no arguments within a lambda expression.

Having said that, wrapping a synchronous function in `Task.Run` is an anti-pattern.

If your method is completely synchronous, you should ideally expose it as such:

```
public IEnumerable<JsonPatchOperation> GetRemoveAllRelationsOperations(IBatchMigrationContext batchContext, WorkItem targetWorkItem)
{
    return targetWorkItem.Relations?
        .Select((r, index) => MigrationHelpers.GetRelationRemoveOperation(index));
}
```

If you cannot change the signature, for example if you are implementing an interface, then use `Task.FromResult` instead:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<JsonPatchOperation>> GetRemoveAllRelationsOperations(IBatchMigrationContext batchContext, WorkItem targetWorkItem)
{
    return Task.FromResult(targetWorkItem.Relations?
        .Select((r, index) => MigrationHelpers.GetRelationRemoveOperation(index)));
}
```

This just wraps the synchronous result in a `Task` object, rather than forcing the lambda to run on the threadpool.

Comment: That works, thanks. `wrapping a synchronous function in Task.Run is an anti-pattern` Hm, interesting. What's the difference between `Task.Run` and `Task.Result`?

Comment: @InteXX Not sure what you mean by this. Could you share your `async` / `await` chain?

Comment: "Async all the way down." An `async` call requires an `async` call, which requires an `async` call, etc. etc. How then to terminate that, when we've reached the end of our call chain and the last lines of code are synchronous? From your reply, it seems to be `Task.FromResult`, but I haven't investigated that yet.

Comment: @InteXX Async starts at the bottom, which is ultimately an I/O operation, and works its way up, not the other way around. If your process doesn't involve asynchronous work, using `Task.Run` just introduces thread switching and the overhead that brings.

Comment: @InteXX [This](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) is a good series to read.

Comment: Top, bottom... I guess it depends on one's perspective. But the problem remains—given that `Task.Run(<synchronous code>)` is an anti-pattern, as you say, how then to properly terminate the chain when the final bit of our code is synchronous and can't be made otherwise? `async`/`await` must remain in order to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Thanks, I like Stephen's stuff. I'll have a go at that. I'm still researching this—your anti-pattern assertion has shaken me up a bit.

Comment: @InteXX `Task.Run` should be used at the highest level possible. Keeping the UI thread free is a valid use case, but that decision should be made at UI level.

Comment: OK, sounds good—but I'm still not seeing how to terminate the chain while avoiding the anti-pattern. Let's take the example at hand: a `Select()` lambda. There's no such thing as `SelectAsync()`, and we have to use an `await` somewhere in that method, so the question is... where? How? Until you mentioned `Task.FromResult` just now, `Task.Run` seemed the only way.

Comment: @InteXX `Select` is a naturally synchronous (CPU-bound) operation, which is why there is no asynchronous equivalent. Don't try to force `GetRemoveAllRelationsOperations` to be `async` when it isn't. If it transpires that synchronous code, such as `GetRemoveAllRelationsOperations`, is causing your UI thread to block, then use `Task.Run` to offload it to the threadpool. Make this decision in your UI code.

Comment: Ah, so it's not so much "don't do this" as it is "choose the right place to do it." Stephen seems to be saying this as well, in the article you linked. Is that it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216437/discussion-between-intexx-and-johnathan-barclay).